# Is there a super-linear lower bound on the time complexity of all solutions of NP complete problems?

Tags: np-complete, lower-bounds

$P \ne NP$ would imply that *any* polynomial is a lower bound on the time complexity of any NP complete problem.

Is *some* non-trivial lower bound known at all?

Comment: In a single-tape Turing machine, any language recognizable by a TM working in $o(n\log n)$ is regular. So you have a lower bound of $\Omega(n\log n)$ on every NP-complete problem (none of them are regular languages).

Comment: There are some results for sublinear space, e.g. [Williams' time-space tradeoff](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/mod-lbs-journal-final.pdf). There are also some circuit lower bounds, but they are only linear; see for example [this recent work](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2016/6458/pdf/LIPIcs-MFCS-2016-45.pdf).

Comment: Forget your requirements. Non-trivial lower bounds *in general* are incredibly rare.